# Org doesn't recognize my agenda file while the value of org-agenda-files show it is correctly aimed to where the file is

Tags: emacs, org-mode

TLDR: I can't see my org agenda even though the file I added to it shows on org-agenda-files

My code in my init.el is the following (I don't know about elisp and I just started using emacs to use org-mode):

```
(require 'org)
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
(setq org-directory "~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/")
(setq org-agenda-files "~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/tareas.org")
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-indent-mode)
```

My Org files are on an icloud Drive which generates that weird path, this because I want to access them using the Beorg app on my iPhone.

Anyway, when I start emacs and press `C-c a` and press `a` to see my agenda it says the following on the echo: Non-existent agenda file ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/#+STARTUP: hidestars

The value of `org-agenda-files` is: "~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/tareas.org"

I do have some code at the beginning of my `tareas.org` file that says `#+STARTUP: hidestars`. Which I don't know how it is causing the issue.

At the beginning I didn't have `(require 'org)` on my init.el which caused another error. I tried to fix it by adding it and changing my code a little bit. What ended up happening is that now I can't see my agenda while before I was able to see it, although I had to manually set it up every time I started emacs.

To further troubleshoot this issue I deleted from my tareas.org file (the one fed to my org agenda) that `#+STARTUP: hidestars` text and now the message is: Non-existent agenda file ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/* Capture configure control

Which is the name of my first heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the "(setq org-agenda-files ..."
and adding the file with command [org-agenda-file-to-front](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Files.html#index-C_002dc-_005b)

It might be that as you've set org-agenda-files to a specific file it assumes that the file contains list of agenda files.

from https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Files.html#DOCF90 :

"If the value of that variable is not a list, but a single file name, then the list of agenda files in maintained in that external file."

Comment: Hi, this fixed it. However, another solution I found is to create a symlink to shorten the path used by org-agenda-files and leave it as: `"~/org/tareas.org"`. I also changed the path of org-directory to `"~/org"`.

Comment: You could write `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Org/tareas.org"))`. I use this command quite often to limit the content of the agenda to a single file.